# Mongodb: AWS Secrets Manager rotation function for Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I am looking for a python lambda function for Mongodb for password rotation.
I know there are Lambda functions for password rotation for DocumentDB, RDS, etc.

Comment: You will likely need to write one yourself. Use one of the other functions as a guideline for how to write a function for MongoDB.

Comment: You can use the examples in https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/tree/master/SecretsManagerMongoDBRotationSingleUser . Note that if you use Atlas, you'll need to use Atlas APIs instead of a mongo driver.